# Why am I not seeing or why I am not seeing. Which one is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Why **am I** not seeing

or

> Why **I am** not seeing

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

As a complete statement (question) it would be:

> Why am I not seeing?

Although, as a complete statement it would rarely sound quite right. If you're talking purely about the capacity to see, you would say:

> Why can't I see?

To reverse the words "I" and "am", would be used in a context such as:

> Let me explain why I am not seeing the solution.